# Selenium how to click/ access an a tag with a href that has a javascript function

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have searched but havent found something similar to what Im trying to do. I'm using java by the way, I'm trying to click/access an a tag with selenium. The issue is that I'm not sure how to go about it. There seems to be a function/event that I need to set off but not quite sure how to. I tried a few ways as get text and clicking but I knew that wasn't going to work. Also I seen there are ways of using JavascriptExecutor but not sure how to use it for my case. I will post the tag below and alsothe function signature, that might help. If theres a similar question please post the link.

```
<a name="DERIVED_SSS_SCL_SSS_ENRL_CART$276$" id="DERIVED_SSS_SCL_SSS_ENRL_CART$276$" ptlinktgt="pt_peoplecode" tabindex="203" onclick="javascript:cancelBubble(event);" href="javascript:submitAction_win0(document.win0,'DERIVED_SSS_SCL_SSS_ENRL_CART$276$');" class="SSSHYPERLINKBOLDSMALL">Enrollment Shopping Cart</a>
```

the signature

```
function submitAction_win0(form, id, event)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any JS. Just use this xpath:

```
"//a[contains(@onclick,'javascript:cancelBubble(event);')]"
```

Be sure the element is clickable, see

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
```

for the case of more matches:

```
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@onclick,'javascript:cancelBubble(event);')]"));
    int elementIndex = 0; // 0 to get first of the 33 mathes, 32 to get the last one
    WebElement element = elements.get(elementIndex);
    element.click();
```

Comment: When using CTRL + F I get about 33 mathces for  "//a[contains(@onclick,'javascript:cancelBubble(event);')]". Also how would i be sure if the element is clickable. Thank you.

Comment: Use xpath that fit only on the desired one element. In genereal: "//foo[contains(@bar,'part or complete value')]"

Comment: I found out that all the tags are not being loaded when runinng my program. I debug it, and went trought the tags only the banner of the page is loaded. Only if I interact with it, all the tags appear.

Comment: Than interact with the banner and wait until desired tag is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

You should use [WebDriverWait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) to avoid NoSuchElementException this way the driver will wait until the element is clickable... it will wait up to 10 seconds you can tell it to wait more if needed...

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.partialLinkText("Student Center")));
element.click();
```

---

Using `click()`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='SSSHYPERLINKBOLDSMALL']"));
element.click();
```

Using `JavascriptExecutor` (Not recommended):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='SSSHYPERLINKBOLDSMALL']"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

You can use other locators too... like `linkText`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.linkText("Enrollment Shopping Cart"));
```

Or `partialLinkText`:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("Shopping Cart"));
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick response. I used CTRL F and when i searched class = "sssHyperLinkBoldSmall" I got about 15 mathces. I tried it anyway to see what will happen. I got this error                     
     "org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to 
     locate element: {"method":"css 
     selector","selector":"a[class='SSSHYPERLINKBOLDSMALL']"}"

Comment: Didn't work it's giving me an NoSuchElementException.  I tried this in my code: this.browser.findElement(By.linkText("Student Center")).click();. The a tag is different tho. I'ts       <a role="menuitem" href="https://home.SSS_CENTER&amp;IsFolder=false&amp;IgnoreParamTempl=FolderPath%2cIsFolder">Student Center</a>

Comment: I tried 10 30 and 60. this is my error: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.linkText: Enrollment Shopping Cart (tried for 60 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval). This is the code I tried.                                                                          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(browser, 60);
              WebElement element  = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Enrollment Shopping Cart")));;
              element.click();

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I thought that was going to work.

Comment: No but I'll give it a shot

Comment: I found out that not all the tags are being loaded when runinng my program. I debug it, and went trought the tags only the banner of the page is loaded. Only if I interact with it, all the tags appear.